# NHIbernate ICriteria conditional disjunction

Tags: nhibernate, conditional-statements, criteria

I've got a working Criteria, but I want to make my method more flexible.

one of the pieces of my criteria looks like this:

```
    .Add(
        nhc.Restrictions.In("GroupID", groupIDs)
        || nhc.Restrictions.Eq("UserIDScheduled", userID));
```

but what I need to do is check if the groupIDs & userID params actually have values before adding them here, because otherwise I'll get unexpected results/query. for instance, If i want to get the entities where GroupID is in x,y,z, but not include the userid in the OR if it's null.

I can have a 3-case IF statement that does this, but it seems like there should be another way to do it in-line? (if userID == null, only .Add(..In(GroupID) ..), if groupIDs == null, etc.)

I'm obviously not very familiar with the ICriteria API so I'm not sure what it's capabilities are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Disjunction like so:

```
var disjunction = new Disjunction();

if (userId != null)
    disjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserIDScheduled", userID));
if (groupIDs != null)
    disjunction.Add(Restrictions.In("GroupID", groupIDs));

criteria.Add(disjunction);
```

Comment: thanks - not sure why I didn't think there were types behind the method chains :-x